# Pandas datframe: Read in multiple textfiles, map them together, aggregate (unique), and return as dictionary

Tags: pandas, aggregate

## Set-up and available data:

I have 3 csv files describing some measurements I have:

- **1st** file: descriptive weather *station* assets (`metgeography.csv`),containing for instance: station number ("`stNo`"), From&To Dates, lat, lon.

```
stNo,station_nm,lat,lon,Date From,Date To 
1002,Name1,45.123,12.123,18/04/2015 23:40,02/08/2020 08:40
1032,Name2,45.345,12.456,14/02/2006 12:10,02/08/2019 08:40
1039,Name3,45.678,12.678,17/02/2005 07:30,01/03/2022 05:40
```

- **2nd** file: timeseries of actual measurement(s), for all stations, based on  (map) between station number and sensor Identification number (`sensorID`). I am **NOT** interested in the actual measured value (`Value`) and I want to **discard** column `dt` (not relevant now), so when reading in the file, I have just dropped these columns. The content of the timeseries looks like:

```
stNo,stType,sensorID,dt,parID,Value
1032,4,22,01/01/2022 01:00,3,1.8
1039,4,1,01/01/2022 01:00,3,15..5
1041,4,1,01/01/2022 01:00,3,12.
1082,4,22,01/01/2022 01:00,3,1.6
1151,4,1,01/01/2022 01:00,3,6.6
1151,4,2,01/01/2022 01:00,4,6.8
1171,4,8,01/01/2022 01:00,2,88
1203,4,1,01/01/2022 01:00,3,11.1
```

- **3rd** file: TablseSensor mapping sensor `name`, sensor `symbol`, `number of decimals` (i.e., precision) and sensor `unit of measure` to each sensor Identification Number `SensorId`. An extract from it, shows what the content looks like:

```
SensorID,en_name,symbol,unit,decimal_num
1,AIR TEMPERATURE 1.2m(av),TAir (av),°C,1
2,AIR TEMPERATURE 1.2m(max),TAir (max),°C,1
3,AIR TEMPERATURE 1.2m(min),TAir (min),°C,1
4,AIR TEMPERATURE 1.2m(s),TAir (s),°C,1
6,RELATIVE HUMIDITY 1.2m(av),RH (av),%,0
7,RELATIVE HUMIDITY 1.2m(max),RH (max),%,0
8,RELATIVE HUMIDITY 1.2m(min),RH (min),%,0
27,RAIN (tot),Rain (tot),mm,1
28,SOIL TEMPERATURE 5cm(av),Soil5 (av),°C,1
29,SOIL TEMPERATURE 5cm(max),Soil5 (max),°C,1
30,SOIL TEMPERATURE 5cm(min),Soil5 (min),°C,1
31,SOIL TEMPERATURE 5cm(s),Soil5 (s),°C,1
32,SOIL TEMPERATURE 10cm(av),Soil10 (av),°C,1
33,SOIL TEMPERATURE 10cm(max),Soil10 (max),°C,1
34,SOIL TEMPERATURE 10cm(min),Soil10 (min),°C,1
35,SOIL TEMPERATURE 10cm(s),Soil10 (s),°C,1
36,SOIL TEMPERATURE 20cm(av),Soil20 (av),°C,1
37,SOIL TEMPERATURE 20cm(max),Soil20 (max),°C,1
38,SOIL TEMPERATURE 20cm(min),Soil20 (min),°C,1
39,SOIL TEMPERATURE 20cm(s),Soil20 (s),°C,1
40,GLOBAL SOLAR RADIATION(av),GlobRad(av),W/m²,0
41,GLOBAL SOLAR RADIATION(max),GlobRad(max),W/m²,0
42,GLOBAL SOLAR RADIATION(min),GlobRad(min),W/m²,0
43,GLOBAL SOLAR RADIATION(s),GlobRad(s),W/m²,0
45,GLOBAL SOLAR RADIATION(tot),GlobRad(tot),W/m²,0
46,DIRECT SOLAR RADIATION(av),DirRadD(av),W/m²,0
```

## Objective & Problem Approach(s)

I want to:

1. **Combine** all 3 files, into 1 single dataframe that would then contain station number, station name, daterange, and all available sensor(s) for THAT station
2. **Rearrange and filter** so to drop duplicates for each station. In essence, I want to expand file number 1 (`metgeography.csv`) so to have a full, comprehensive description of my asset (what, where, from/to when, Id station code). **It is important to note that sensor names happen to be listed redundantly, when doing the mapping (merging), as they measure constantly over time. Thus, is is necessary to aggregate by unique value, after having group by station name (see below)**
3. **Store on disk, for fast uploading**, at a later stage. This newly created, filtered, polished, comprehensive file, will be used when sending queries to pick the right weather station(**s**) [plural!] from a webpage. Therefore, calculations and preprocessing should be made offline. When user request info about station (after slicing), the according station (names and or codes) are sent as a dictionary (already achieved):

## So far:

```
# merge, polish and set a new index the following files: 
#     df is metgeography.csv (point 1 of my bullet list): 
      df      = pd.read_csv(metgeogr.csv).set_index('stNo')
#     hourly is the timeseries (point 2 of my bullet list)
#     sensorID


# also map to paramater ID, not described here above but not relevant! 
R = sensor.merge(hourly, on='SensorID').merge(par, on='parID').set_index('stNo')

# merge with metgeogr.csv
R = df.merge(R,on='stNo')

# drop unwanted, goup by station name (use as "pivot"), and remove duplicate station names 
final = R.drop(['dt','Date To '],axis=1).groupby('stNo').agg(['unique']).drop('decimal_num',axis=1)
```

## Getting quite close to the result, but not yet good enough.

The result seems satisfying, at first glance. However, I am still failing when trying to implement the following:

- there are some tuples in the way I cannot get rid of (making everything so annoyingly complicated). There is this `unique` label always appearing and the resulting dataframe is an `ndarray` which seems to be preventing me from doing some trivial operations.
- I would like to have a nested structure like:

```
station name: {
    lat  : 23.456,
    long : 34.567,
    from : 01.01.2020,
    to   : 01.02.2020, 
    variables: 
    {
    Soil10:
        { 
            unit   : K 
            method : mean
            name   : SOIL TEMPERATURE 10cm(s)
        }
    Soil20:
        { 
            unit   : K 
            method : mean
            name   : SOIL TEMPERATURE 20cm(s)
        }
     // repeats for all **UNIQUE** (dropping duplicates!) variables of that station 
    }
}
```

The above should look something like `ncdump` (if you know climate data).

See text described above for a detailed explanation.
I also tried with stack, and MultiIndex, but could not get far...

Edit for @mozway
To reproduce the example, use:

```
filename    = 'metgeography.csv'
hourlyData  = 'hourly.csv'
sensorId    = 'tblSensors.csv'

df      = pd.read_csv(filename).set_index('stNo')
hourly  = pd.read_csv(hourlyData).drop(['Value'],axis=1).rename(columns={'sensorID':'SensorID'}).set_index('SensorID')
sensor  = pd.read_csv(sensorId, index_col=False).set_index('SensorID')


R = sensor.merge(hourly, on='SensorID').set_index('stNo')
R = df.merge(R,on='stNo')

final = R.drop(['dt','Date To'],axis=1).groupby('stNo').agg(['unique']).drop('decimal_num',axis=1)
```

Now, when inspecting `final`, i.e. what I hope to be my result, I get:

```
station_nm       lat       lon       ...   unit stType  parID
unique           unique    unique    ... unique unique unique
stNo                                 ...                     
1039    [Name3]  [45.678]  [12.678]  ...   [°C]    [4]    [3]

[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

Important: why is StationID 1032 not whowing up? The elements to map it, are indeed there (`SensorId=4`), but is not appearing in `final`..
Also, under each colname I get `unqie` and my dataframe is an `ndarray`, as mentioned above - how can I get rid of it?

@mozway: Did this help, making it more reproducible?

Comment: Your example code is not reproducible, please ensure it can be run and give the current output that you have